# Does f2py support a function with type only as intent(inout)?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, f2py

I am connecting a purely-F90 cosmological library to a python code in order to make some plots by writing interconnection functions in F90, which uses several functions in the library mentioned above by, e.g.,

> USE cosmology_functions

where cosmology_functions is a module including some functions with underscores like 'init_cosmology'. I successfully compiled this interconnection but when I try to import it within my python script I found this issue:

> ImportError: $PATH$/Interconnection.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: __cosmology_functions_MOD_init_cosmology

What is weird that several functions are called before 'init_cosmology' and I received no error reported. So I doubted whether the function itself has caused the error is used with f2py. The input and output of this function is simply like:

> subroutine init_cosmology(cosm)
>
> TYPE(cosmology), INTENT(INOUT) :: cosm

where parameters are added to cosm inside this function, makes the input dimension and output dimension different with each other. Is this an intrinsic issue of f2py? Or have I made a wrong guess?

The compiler is GNU fortran 9.3.0 and the python version is 3.8.5.

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the components of `cosmology`? Are the components interoperable?

Comment: @King Thanks for noticing this question. The type `cosmology` has several cosmological parameters presented in `REAL(8)` and several logical and integer terms as to contain several information like whether the Dark Matter is Warm or which cosmological model should be used. No components out of with these three are used.

Comment: Maybe f2py does not support user-defined types...? https://foreign-fortran.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/f2py.html  A recent tool may be helpful for this https://github.com/jameskermode/f90wrap/ but I have no experience with it (so not sure if it is good for your purpose...) In my case, I use opaque pointers for derived types.